# Django Endless Pagination somehow blocking my custom javascript

Tags: django, jquery, django-endless-pagination

I am using [the twitter style endless pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html) for one of my projects. the problem is that my ajax logic works just fine for my first 10 posts (so the first page) but when I go down and Endless Pagination loads more posts, my ajax stops working for them. I am not sure my.

Thats how I've been stacking my js

```
<script src="/site_media/endless_pagination/endless.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/site_media/endless_pagination/endless_on_scroll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/site_media/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http:/site_media/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="site_media/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

so for example tooltip works just fine for my first 10 posts, but then when pagination loads the next posts, tooltip doesn't seem to work for them.

Comment: Was there any error message in the admin javascript console?

Comment: Can you add the js that actually activates/sets up the endless pagination

Comment: Does it work for the previous ones after you've loaded the new posts ? If so it just means that the jquery that handles the tootip is not aware of the new post objects. Please Confirm this so we can tackle it.

Comment: @Paulo yes it still works for the pervious ones

Comment: Ok, so basically bootstrap's tooltip is not aware of the newly added objects. I'm not an expert on jquery so I'm not sure on a work around. However this is a known issue https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/272. As a last resort I would just destroy the plugin once the new document loads and initialize it again. However again i'm not an expert so it's best to hear it from someone that is ;). Good luck

Comment: its not just bootstrap, even my custom JS is having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was, I was suposed to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). This Attaches an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. So when new posts load, my jQuery logic applies to them as well.